# Trigger vs procedure to update a calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I coded a trigger that calculated the value of a column (expiryDate) whenever the value of another column (productionDate) changed from null, and my professor told me I should have used a stored procedure:

```
create or alter trigger tg_expiry_date
on product
after insert, update
as
begin
    if exists (select productionDate
               from inserted as i
               where productionDate is not null)
    begin
        begin try
            declare @orderId int = (    select max(orderId) -- avoids updating previously inserted rows
                                        from inserted ) 

            declare @date date =   (    select productionDate 
                                        from inserted
                                        where orderId = @orderId )

            begin tran
            update product
                set expiryDate = (      select dateadd(day, 90, @date) -- adds 90 days to the production date
                                        from inserted 
                                        where orderId = @orderId 
                                 )
                where orderId = @orderId 
            commit tran
        end try

        begin catch
            if @@trancount > 0
            begin
                rollback tran
                exec usp_showerrorinfo
            end
        end catch
    end
end
go
```

However, I don't really agree with her suggestion. Using a procedure every time a value changes can be too tedious and it should be automatically calculated. Why did she tell me that? I guess it can be a little spaghetti-code-ish, and the `max` in the `set` shouldn't exist, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Aside... your professor should have told you that this trigger has a fatal flaw: it assumes that only one row gets inserted or updated at a time. What happens if you insert/update two or more rows at a time?

Comment: The expiry date is just the order date + 90 days. You need a computed (calculated) column, nothing more.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code - you have much to learn before you attempt to write triggers.  More importantly, if your **teacher** says to use one technique, it is in your best interest to use that technique. Doesn't matter if you disagree; you do not have sufficient experience or skill to make that judgement.

Comment: I assume you teacher is suggesting that you insert and update to your table using a SP so you can do this sort of thing at the same time? Which is often better than a trigger, but certainly not better than a computed column as already stated. And if you did find yourself writing such a trigger it should consist of a single update statement which joins in inserted. You won't need to check exists, or pull values one at a time, thats a complete anti-pattern for T-SQL.

Comment: You won't even need a transaction as triggers run inside an implicit transaction and you aren't doing enough separate actions to need to create an inner transaction.

Comment: "Why did she tell me that?" - ask *her*. This is the literal definition of a teachable moment. You may find that you still don't agree with her after she's given her reasoning. But either way you'll have walked away with a new perspective!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a computed column, ideal for a scenario such as this.

```
alter table product drop column ExpiryDate;
go
alter table product add ExpiryDate as dateadd(day, 90, productionDate);
```